# Getting #N/A in Index Match Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formulas

I am using index-match fomula but I'm having an error in the middle of the data.

```
#   EE CODE     EE CODE IN PREVFILE
302 54011       54011
304 40448       40448
305 16228       #N/A
306 74427       #N/A
309 15313       #N/A
310 09624       #N/A
311 90422       #N/A
312 73025       #N/A
314 06028       #N/A
315 22322       #N/A
316 59421       #N/A
318 07502       #N/A
326 54410       #N/A
327 00934       #N/A
```

Line 305 and 306 are not available in the source file (array) so it is understood that it will result to #N/A. However, the next lines starting from 309, it still gives #N/A even if they are available in the source file (array).

This is my formula:

```
=INDEX('PrevFile'!$A2:$Y164,MATCH(Valid!A3,'PrevFile'!A2:A164,0),MATCH(Valid!$B$1,'PrevFile'!A$1:Y$1,0))
```

I will input the formula in the first cell then click autofill and above is the results.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you need to fix the other ranges

Should this `A2:A164` be `A$2:A$164` ? Otherwise autofill will change the range referenced.

And `'PrevFile'!$A2:$Y164` might need to be `'PrevFile'!$A$2:$Y$164`. Thanks to @Glitch_Doctor for spotting that.

These are called **absolute** cell references (when you see the $) and fix the range being referenced so doesn't shift with autofill.